# Removing half of H_1 of a 2-manifold through a 3-dimensional bounding manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $M$ be a 2-manifold. If $X$ is a 3-manifold such that $\partial X = M$, we know that the image of the boundary map $H_2(X, M) \rightarrow H_1(M)$ has rank equal to one half the rank of $H_1(M)$.

My question is that given any half rank subspace/subgroup $C$ of $H_1(M)$, can I always find a 3-manifold $X_C$ such that $\partial X_C = M$ and the image of the boundary map $H_2(X_C, M) \rightarrow H_1(M)$ is exactly $C$? If the answer is not, what is the constraint on $C$ for such a 3-manifold $X_C$ to exist?

Comment: $M$ definitely needs to be oriented, otherwise you won't even find any $X$ bounded by $M$. Also, a necessary condition is that your subspace forms a Lagrangian subspace with respect to the intersection pairing on $H_1(M)$ (or is orthogonal to a Lagrangian subspace of $H^1(M)$ with respect to the cup product). I have the feeling that that might be sufficient, using a surgery argument, but I am not sure (hence a comment instead of an answer).

Comment: @AchimKrause Thanks for the comment. I am indeed mostly interested in the case of orientable 2-manifold $M$. Could you elaborate on the surgery argument that yields the conclusion that the subspace $C$ has to form a Lagrangian subspace of $H^1(M)$ ?